# How to stuff multiple imageViews into a single row (allow overlapping)?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a certain number of thumbnail images which I would like to lay out left-aligned but if the images don't fit on the screen I would like each image to overlap its left neighbour.

It would look like a cover flow or carousel view, but static.

The number of images to show in one row is known from the start and will not change. Also: No need for 3D effects. Just flat, horizontally stuffed, overlapping images.

I tried LinearLayout with negative margins: Can't determine how big a margin to set.

I tried PercentageRelativeLayout: Cannot achieve the left-aligned behaviour

Please show me how to do it programmatically.

A poor sketch of what I want:
[image: A poor sketch of what i want]

I implemented Chris Parkers suggestion (although I have to do it programmatically, I test with axml):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/loPreviews"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="@dimen/filePreviewHeight"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/filePreviewHeight"
          android:src="@drawable/img1"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="@dimen/filePreviewHeight"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/filePreviewHeight"
          android:src="@drawable/img2"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- more images-->
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem with this solution is, that the images have different aspect ratios and they are cropped the wrong way or fit into the square with borders. No `android:scaleType` allows me to crop it right (preserve the full height and cut off only the right part).

That can be resolved by setting the `layout_width` of each `ImageView` according to each image's aspect ratio. Also, set the weights equal to the images' width for better distribution. The rightmost LinearLayout gets width wrap_content, in order to show the full image.
BUT this solution does not left-align the images if not all the horizontal space is used!

Comment: Do all the ImageViews have the same size? e.g.: All ImageViews are always 100dp x 100dp?

Comment: I could crop them to equal squares, yes. Not preferred, but acceptable!

Comment: show some of your code so we can help you

Comment: I don't think any of my non working code would help. I'd rather need some hint where to start. Or maybe someone knows the FlowLayout well enough to be able to help me modify that..? I'm just guessing and don't know where to start, really...

Answer (score -2):

You could use LinearLayout as your parent layout. Then wrap every image in its own LinearLayout. Every Image container should have a weight value defined and they all should have the same value, so that the space in your parent layout is equally split into the same amount for every image container. Your images need to have width and height declared to prevent the ImageView from resizing the Image to fit the container layout. It's a very ugly solution but it works i guess.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <!-- Repeat this for every image -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Repeat this for every image -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ... -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I updated my question stating my remaining issue.. any more ideas from your side maybe?